# How do I decode a dictionary of bytes to utf-8?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the values of a dictionary from bytes to strings as the backend only supports primitive types.

```
 oledata = {
            'macros': macros,
            'data': analysis
        }
        s = str(oledata)
        save_data_to_s3(json.dumps(s), ['olevba3'])
```

As you can see, the values of this dict are bytes. Now this code will execute without errors on my test sample but the output has the b' prefix in front of the values (data), which will break the database. Dict's also have no decode() functionality which is why I used str(), but it must be doing something wrong since the values are still coming out with the b' prefix. Which leads to my general question, how do you decode the values of a dictionary to utf-8 format?

Answer (score 0):

```
my_str = b"Hello" # b means its a byte string
new_str = my_str.decode('utf-8') # Decode using the utf-8 encoding
print(new_str)
```